# Accumulating count of answers using Java lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

I have list of form data entries, each `DataEntry` contains data field which is of type `Map<String, Object>`. The String key is the dynamic field name (survey question), and value is the choice answered for that particular question.

Out of the list, how can I get count of unique answers for each field name (question), something like this I assume? `Map<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, Integer>`, where the outer map key is the fieldXXXX, its value map key (string) is the unique answer, and key Integer the count of that answer

For testing purpose, from database they come out as Strings which I map to DTOs where the mapper maps to proper json map:

```
DataEntry entry1 = new DataEntry();
entry1.setData("{field9294: '4', field9296: '3', field9319: '5', field9321: '5', field9323: '3', field9325: '3', field9327: '5', field9329: '7'}");
DataEntry entry2 = new DataEntry();
entry2.setData("{field9294: '3', field9296: '2', field9319: '3', field9321: '3', field9323: '5', field9325: '2', field9327: '4', field9329: '4'}");
DataEntry entry3 = new DataEntry();
entry3.setData("{field9294: '5', field9296: '5', field9319: '4', field9321: '4', field9323: '3', field9325: '3', field9327: '4', field9329: '8'}");

List<DataEntry> dataEntries = Arrays.asList(entry1, entry2, entry3);

List<FormDataDTO> dtos = dataEntries.stream().map(mapper::dataEntryToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So the list of dtos looks like this:

[image: DTO list]

**End goal**

Let's take first field **field9294**, in 3 data entries there are 3 unique answers given: 4, 3, 5. Here all should have count of 1.
Now **field9327** has answers 5, 4, 4. Here we count 5 once, 4 twice.

General idea would be to plot the data for each question separately so I can draw a chart and decorate the result as percentage for example.

As I see then getting `Map<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, Integer>` would be enough to achieve that, but is there any efficient way using fancy lambda tricks as I haven't been able to figure out myself. For result I expect something like this:

```
Map
 key: "field9294"
 values: "4" -> 1
         "3" -> 1
         "5" -> 1
 key: "field9327"
 values: "5" -> 1
         "4" -> 2
```

etc..

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
**All pass, thanks for the solution!**

```
assertEquals("[3=1, 4=1, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9294").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[2=1, 3=1, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9296").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[3=1, 4=1, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9319").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[3=1, 4=1, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9321").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[3=2, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9323").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[2=1, 3=2]", answerCountsByField.get("field9325").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[4=2, 5=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9327").entrySet().toString());
assertEquals("[4=1, 7=1, 8=1]", answerCountsByField.get("field9329").entrySet().toString());
```

Edit2:
**Looking for solution also to this structure**. For results I only care about true answers, false are redundant for plotting as this structure maps to checkbox list

```
{"field6696":{"1":true,"2":true},"field7994":{"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":true}}
{"field6696":{"1":false,"2":true},"field7994":{"1":false,"2":true,"3":true}}
{"field6696":{"1":false,"2":true},"field7994":{"1":false,"2":true,"3":false,"4":true}}
{"field6696":{"1":false,"2":true,"3":true},"field7994":{"1":true,"2":true,"3":false}}
{"field6696":{"1":false,"2":true},"field7994":{"1":true,"2":true,"3":true,"4":true}}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for either a reduce operation or a custom Collector here

Comment: I've tried many different approaches but lacking the knowledge with all of the functions and cannot find a proper solution. I'd appreciate some help with some example code perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with a Stream, so I would avoid collecting the FormDataDTO objects into a List.  Change this:

```
List<FormDataDTO> dtos = dataEntries.stream().map(mapper::dataEntryToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to just this:

```
Stream<FormDataDTO> dtos = dataEntries.stream().map(mapper::dataEntryToDto);
```

Then you can collect them using a `groupingBy` call that itself uses another Collector to create Map values:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> answerCountsByField =
    dtos.flatMap(dto -> dto.getData().entrySet().stream()).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue(),
                Collectors.counting())));
```

If you want the counts to be Integers rather than Longs, you can use `collectingAndThen` to transform each Long value:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> answerCountsByField =
    dtos.flatMap(dto -> dto.getData().entrySet().stream()).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue(),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue))));
```

Comment: Wow, that really seems to work, I wasn't even close. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Vaelyr it seems to... I'd be worrying if I were you; try and understand what that does :p

Comment: I studied and played around a bit, no need to worry, getting it clearly now :) Thanks again.

Comment: @fge I tend to agree. I personally would have used old-fashioned loops, so I'd have code I would understand when I look at it a month from now.

Comment: @VGR I endorse your comment :p There is a saying that code is WORM (Write Once, Read Many), which I wholeheartedly subscribe to ;)

Comment: The nesting would get rather ugly I assume, resulting in another nested map, but say I have an object now instead of single value, is it possible to include that in the same grouping somehow or rather have a separate one? First one would work for radiobutton list kind of structure, I missed that I also have checkbox fields that has structure like this, assuming I want to count all true answers for each question, any ideas? `{field6696: {1: true, 2: true, 3: true}}`

Comment: @Vaelyr I'm sure it's possible, but it would indeed get ugly (or should I say, uglier).  Plain old loops seem like the better option.  You also might want to consider writing some custom classes, with meaningful method names like 'getField' and 'getCount', rather than Maps of Maps of Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something this for now and that structure actually works for both cases as the end result can be exactly the same, only difference is the parsing as I have to go deeper by one map. I tried the same with the functions, then I had to check the type where is `entry.getValue()` as in one case it's String for other case it's another Map, but it really looked bad.

I put the grouping logic into the test to post here, data includes both types of structured data, single value and objects.

Maybe could suggest any improvements here?

```
  @Test
  public void multiValueLists_answerCountsByField() throws Exception {

    List<DataEntry> entries = new ArrayList<DataEntry>() {
      {
        add(new DataEntry("{field1000: {1: true, 2: true, 3: true}, field2000: {1: true, 2: true}, field3000: '1', field4000: '1', field5000: '1'}"));
        add(new DataEntry("{field1000: {1: true, 2: true, 3: false}, field2000: {1: true, 2: false}, field3000: '1', field4000: '2', field5000: '2'}"));
        add(new DataEntry("{field1000: {1: false, 2: true, 3: true}, field2000: {1: true}, field3000: '1', field4000: '2', field5000: '3'}"));
      }
    };

    Stream<FormDataDTO> dtoStream = entries.stream().map(mapper::dataEntryToDto);

    Map<String, Map<String, AtomicInteger>> answers = new LinkedTreeMap<>();

    dtoStream.forEach(dto -> dto.getData().entrySet()
      .forEach(field -> {
        answers.putIfAbsent(field.getKey(), new LinkedTreeMap<>());
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> values = answers.get(field.getKey());

        if (field.getValue() instanceof Map)
          ((Map<String, Boolean>) field.getValue()).entrySet().stream()
            .filter(value -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(value.getValue()))
            .forEach(value -> {
              values.putIfAbsent(value.getKey(), new AtomicInteger());
              values.get(value.getKey()).incrementAndGet();
            });
        else {
          values.putIfAbsent(field.getValue().toString(), new AtomicInteger());
          values.get(field.getValue().toString()).incrementAndGet();
        }
      }));

    assertThat(field(answers, "field1000"), is("[1=2, 2=3, 3=2]"));
    assertThat(field(answers, "field2000"), is("[1=3, 2=1]"));
    assertThat(field(answers, "field3000"), is("[1=3]"));
    assertThat(field(answers, "field4000"), is("[1=1, 2=2]"));
    assertThat(field(answers, "field5000"), is("[1=1, 2=1, 3=1]"));
  }
```